# Linear Transformations - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a problem with this exercise.
I think it can be solved with the properties of linear transformations [ T(v+w) = T(v) + T(w) and T(cv) = cT(v) ] but I'm not sure if it's valid and how to use it in this context.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTm0D.png)

//Here is the exercise if you can´t see the image//

Let V be a vector space and let T : V → V a linear transformation such that T($2v_1-3v_2$) = $5v_1 + 3v_2$ and T($−3v_1+5v_2$) = $4v_1 + 3v_2$. Write T($v_1$)  and  T($v_2$) in terms of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: By linearity of $T$ you have $2T(v_1)-3T(v_2) = 5v_1+3v_2$. Do the same for the second equation. Then multiply the first equation by $3$, the second by $2$ and add the two new equations to solve for $T(v_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2 & -3\\-3 & 5\end{pmatrix}$ transforms coordinates with respect to basis $v_1, v_2$

to those with respect to basis $2v_1-3v_2, -3v_1+5v_2$.

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}5&4\\3&3\end{pmatrix}$ represents $T$ with coordinates with respect to $2v_1-3v_2, -3v_1+5v_2$ in the domain

and $v_1,v_2$ for the range.

Therefore, the columns of $\begin{pmatrix}5&4\\3&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & -3\\-3 & 5\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$ give the images of $v_1$ and $v_2$ under $T$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

$$v_1=5(2v_1-3v_2)+3(-3v_1+5v_2)$$

$$v_2=3(2v_1-3v_2)+2(-3v_1+5v_2)$$