# Find the matrix that induces T

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1 = (-1,-1)$ and $v_2= (3,4)$. The set $B=\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^2$.

Let $T: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ be a linear transformation such that $$T(v_1)= 8v_1+2v_2 \\ T(v_2)= 2v_1+4v_2$$

What is the matrix that induces $T$?

I tried to set up a system and solve for the four entries of the matrix but I keep getting it wrong and I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411644/linear-transformations-linear-algebra)

Comment: The matrix in the standard basis?

Comment: To find $T((1,0))$, note $(1,0)=-4v_1-v_2$; to find $T((0,1))$, note $(0,1)=3v_1+v_2$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics stack exchange.  Have a look at MathJax to improve the mathematics of your questions

Comment: Find T(1,0) and T(0,1) and express them w.r.t the ordered basis (1,0),(0,1).then write the coefficients in columns of a matrix that constitutes the matrix of T w.r.t standard bases.

Comment: How exactly do you find T(1,0) and T(0,1)? I get the bit leading up to that but I'm stuck on how to find the transformation